# What is "reactive circuits" in "Frequency analysis of reactive circuits"

Tags: electric-circuits

Here is original text, please ignore the colors:

> - 1.7 Impedance and reactance
>
>   - 1.7.1 Frequency analysis of reactive circuits
>   - 1.7.2 Reactance of inductors
>   - 1.7.3 Voltages and currents as complex numbers
>   - 1.7.2 Reactance of capacitors and inductors

I don't know what is meaning of "reactive", so I look it at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/reactive).

There is only one meaning: *reacting to events or situations rather than acting first to change or prevent something*.

I feel like this may not be quite right. So what is meaning of "reactive" at here?

Comment: In the context of linear network theory satisfying Kirchhoff's voltage and current laws *reactive* means a network that is dissipation free. These are the passive circuits that do not contain resistors but they may contain inductors, capacitors and transformers.

Comment: @hyportnex Does "dissipation free" mean that  "No dissipation"?

Comment: yes, no dissipation

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @Amit  I understand, I will pay attention to it next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reactive" in electrical circuits  means a circuit component's *resistance to a change* in current or voltage. For a capacitance, it is *resistance to change in voltage*. For inductance, it is resistance to *change* in current.

Resistance simply determines the amount of current for a given voltage or the amount of voltage for a given current, per Ohm's law.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Tom you’re very welcome